# Is "UWP" and "Immersive" app the same thing? And if not, what's the difference?

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to understand the terminology Microsoft is using. When [`IsImmersiveProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448383(v=vs.85).aspx) returns `TRUE` does it also mean that the process is a `UWP` app as reported by the [`TokenIsAppContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx) query on its token?

Here's a small code snippet to illustrate what I mean:

```
HANDLE hProc = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
if (hProc)
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    if (::OpenProcessToken(hProc, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        DWORD dwAppContainer = 0;
        DWORD dwDummy = 0;
        if (::GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenIsAppContainer, &dwAppContainer, sizeof(dwAppContainer), &dwDummy))
        {
            wprintf(L"isUWP=%d\n", dwAppContainer);
        }

        ::CloseHandle(hToken);
    }

    wprintf(L"isImmersive=%d\n", ::IsImmersiveProcess(hProc));

    ::CloseHandle(hProc);
}
```

In other words, can a process be `UWP` and not `Immersive`, and vice versa?

*EDIT:* Looking inside `IsImmersiveProcess` API shows the following quite simple logic. Unfortunately `NtUserGetProcessUIContextInformation` and `PROCESS_UICONTEXT_INFORMATION` seem to be undocumented. I can only guess that the value `0` stands for "regular" Win32 process and `1` and `2` for `immersive` app. Not sure what would differ `1` from `2` though?

[image]

*EDIT2:* According to [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)'s find below in comments the `NtUserGetProcessUIContextInformation` function may've been declared as such:

```
enum PROCESS_UICONTEXT{
    PROCESS_UICONTEXT_DESKTOP = 0,
    PROCESS_UICONTEXT_IMMERSIVE,
    PROCESS_UICONTEXT_IMMERSIVE_BROKER,
    PROCESS_UICONTEXT_IMMERSIVE_BROWSER
};

enum PROCESS_UI_FLAGS{
    PROCESS_UIF_NONE = 0,
    PROCESS_UIF_AUTHORING_MODE,
    PROCESS_UIF_RESTRICTIONS_DISABLED
};

struct PROCESS_UICONTEXT_INFORMATION{
    PROCESS_UICONTEXT Context;
    PROCESS_UI_FLAGS flags;
};

BOOL WINAPI NtUserGetProcessUIContextInformation(HANDLE hProc, PROCESS_UICONTEXT_INFORMATION* pProcInfo);
```

Comment: I think Immersive app means any Windows Store app, which includes UWP and Win8 Metro.

Comment: I think it is still related to an immersive mode as in augmented reality. And I think it is [supported](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/app_views) for UWP apps only.

Comment: `IsImmersiveProcess` is true for processes that aren't app containers such as explorer.exe and RuntimeBroker.exe. In such cases I see that `USER32!guiContextInfo` (global UI context information) is 2 instead of 1, and `IsImmersiveProcess` is true for either value when querying the current process via the -1 pseudo handle. For other processes, I assume the `NtUserGetProcessUIContextInformation` system call works similarly.

Comment: @eryksun: Yeah, I looked into that myself. The `IsImmersiveProcess` API calls undocumented `NtUserGetProcessUIContextInformation` that takes as a 2nd parameter a pointer to a `struct` consisting of two `DWORD`s and then if the 1st DWORD is 1 or 2, it returns `true`, meaning that yes, it's an Immersive app and it's 0, then no. I'm curious though, do you know what those values stand for? (`PROCESS_UICONTEXT_INFORMATION` as shown from the disassembly I posted above.)

Comment: I found `PROCESS_UICONTEXT_INFORMATION` in the symbols for uxtheme.dll. It consists of `PROCESS_UICONTEXT` and `PROCESS_UI_FLAGS`. The former includes `PROCESS_UICONTEXT_DESKTOP` (0), `PROCESS_UICONTEXT_IMMERSIVE`, `PROCESS_UICONTEXT_IMMERSIVE_BROKER`, `PROCESS_UICONTEXT_IMMERSIVE_BROWSER` -- and the latter includes `PROCESS_UIF_NONE` (0), `PROCESS_UIF_AUTHORING_MODE`, `PROCESS_UIF_RESTRICTIONS_DISABLED`.

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks! Am I safe to assume that it translates into the declarations I posted above? Also, just from curiosity, what did you use to find those definitions in the symbols?

Comment: I just used a local kernel debugger. I looked up the Process object address of explorer.exe via `!process <explorer pid> 0`, attached to it via `.process /r /p address`, reloaded all module symbols via `.reload /f`, and used `dt PROCESS_UICONTEXT_INFORMATION .` to search all loaded modules for the data type definition. I just tried again and found it referenced in wpnapps.dll this time.

Comment: @eryksun: Very cool. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Immersive" is the old name for the UWP apps. It was their initial name on Windows 8 before calling them "metro", "store" and then "universal" app.

Any app coming from the store and based on the *new* WinRT API is an "immersive" app. Immersive was chosen because the app were executed full screen on Windows 8.

The MSDN documentation is clearing the ambiguity:

> IsImmersiveProcess function
>
> Determines whether the process belongs to a Windows Store app.

The MSDN page is available for [IsImmersiveProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448383(v=vs.85).aspx)

To summarize:

- All the Store/WinRT/UWP applications run in an app container. This is enforce by the OS.
- *Legacy* win32 apps can **choose** to run in a app container to improve their security. Each app has to decide what it want.

Comment: What about desktop applications, packaged up in a Windows App package using the [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root), distributed through the Windows Store?

Comment: They should have the same behavior as the "true" store apps since they are wrapped in an app container by the bridge converter but I couldn't find the confirmation. :(